# Show that there is eigenvector that all composition is real number

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> If $A$ is a real matrix and $\lambda$ is a real eigenvalue of $A$, then there is a real eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda$.

How can I prove this?

Answer (score 0):

Use that $$\det(A-\lambda\operatorname{Id})=0.$$

Answer (score 0):

Use the Row-echelon form on $A-\lambda I$.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Then, does the eigenvector become the zero-vector?

Comment: $Av = \lambda v\implies (A-\lambda I)v=0$

Comment: @user571511 The zero-vector is by definition not an eigenvector. For example, it would be the eigenvector of every linear operator, since $A0 = 0$ if $A$ is linear. Also, the corresponding eigenvalue wouldn't be well-defined, since for all $\lambda$ it is true that $A0 = 0 = \lambda 0$.

Answer (score 0):

If $z\in\Bbb C^n$ is an eigenvector then $z=x+iy$ where $x,y\in\Bbb R$. If the eigenvalue  $\lambda$ is real this shows that $$Ax+iAy=\lambda x+i\lambda y,$$hence $Ax=\lambda x$ and $Ay=\lambda y$.